# Lock status bar orientation in separate UIWindow

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I have a case where I need to create a new `UIWindow` inside my application. I also want the new window to be locked in portrait orientation, but my app's original window should **NOT** be locked in portrait orientation.

I am setting up my new window like so:

```
newWindow = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height))
newWindow?.rootViewController = ViewController2()
newWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And `ViewController2` locks orientation with:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
```

The problem is, when the new window is shown, and the user rotates the device, the app itself will lock in portrait, but the status bar will rotate to landscape mode:
[image]

**How can I make sure the status bar also locks in portrait inside my new window?**

In case anyone wants to see this in action in a simple project: https://github.com/rajohns08/StatusBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this documentation for your problem
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiinterfaceorientationmask

or
The solution is in the app delegate. You can handle supported orientations for every window separately, there:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
   // check, which window is asking and return the mask
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this delegate method, but checking the window passed into the method didn't work. I had to check the UIApplication's keyWindow and return the appropriate mask.

Comment: @AdamJohns What else did you do to get it to work? I tried this and the status bar is still rotated for me.